# Python number-like class that remembers arithmetic operations?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there exists a python module that would allow me to do something like this:

```
x = MagicNumber()
x.value = 3
y = 2 * (x + 2) ** 2 - 8
print y   # 42
x.value = 2
print y   # 24
```

So `MagicNumber` would implement all the special operator methods, and they would all return instances of MagicNumber, while keeping track of what operations are performed. Is there such a class?

**EDIT: clarification**

I want to use this in a module that should remember a lot of parameters of some arbitrary calculation that the user wishes to perform. So the user will set the parameters and then use them to produce his result. Then if he decides he'd like to alter a parameter, the change is reflected in his result immediately. So a very simplified usage session with only one parameter instance would look like:

```
p = MyParams()
p.distance = 13.4           # I use __getattr__ and __setattr__ such that
p.speed = 3.14              # __getattr__ returns MagicNumber instances
time = p.distance / p.speed
```

**EDIT 2: more clarification**

Okay, I'll do what I should have done from the start. I'll provide context.

You are an engineer and you're to produce a LaTeX document detailing the workings and properties of some prototype gadget. It is a task you'll do repeatedly for different prototypes. You write a small LaTeX python interface. For each prototype you create a python module that generates the requisite document. In it you type out the LaTeX code while calculating variables as they are needed, so that the calculations are in context. After a while you notice two problems:

1. The number of variables and parameters makes locals a mess and the variable names are hard to remember. You should group them into categories to keep track of them all.
2. You sometimes need to redo the same calculation, which is spread over the last couple of chapters and a dozen lines, with one or more parameters changed. You should find some way to avoid code duplication.

Out of this problem comes the original question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import operator

MAKE_BINARY  = lambda opfn : lambda self,other : BinaryOp(self, asMagicNumber(other), opfn)
MAKE_RBINARY = lambda opfn : lambda self,other : BinaryOp(asMagicNumber(other), self, opfn)

class MagicNumber(object):
    __add__  = MAKE_BINARY(operator.add)
    __sub__  = MAKE_BINARY(operator.sub)
    __mul__  = MAKE_BINARY(operator.mul)
    __radd__ = MAKE_RBINARY(operator.add)
    __rsub__ = MAKE_RBINARY(operator.sub)
    __rmul__ = MAKE_RBINARY(operator.mul)
    # __div__  = MAKE_BINARY(operator.div)
    # __rdiv__ = MAKE_RBINARY(operator.div)
    __truediv__ = MAKE_BINARY(operator.truediv)
    __rtruediv__ = MAKE_RBINARY(operator.truediv)
    __floordiv__ = MAKE_BINARY(operator.floordiv)
    __rfloordiv__ = MAKE_RBINARY(operator.floordiv)

    def __neg__(self, other):
        return UnaryOp(self, lambda x : -x)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.eval()

class Constant(MagicNumber):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value_ = value

    def eval(self):
        return self.value_

class Parameter(Constant):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parameter, self).__init__(0.0)

    def setValue(self, v):
        self.value_ = v

    value = property(fset=setValue, fget=lambda self: self.value_)

class BinaryOp(MagicNumber):
    def __init__(self, op1, op2, operation):
        self.op1 = op1
        self.op2 = op2
        self.opn = operation

    def eval(self):
        return self.opn(self.op1.eval(), self.op2.eval())


class UnaryOp(MagicNumber):
    def __init__(self, op1, operation):
        self.op1 = op1
        self.operation = operation

    def eval(self):
        return self.opn(self.op1.eval())

asMagicNumber = lambda x : x if isinstance(x, MagicNumber) else Constant(x)
```

And here it is in action:

```
x = Parameter()
# integer division
y = 2*x*x + 3*x - x//2

# or floating division
# y = 2*x*x + 3*x - x/2

x.value = 10
print(y.value)
# prints 225

x.value = 20
print(y.value)
# prints 850

# compute a series of x-y values for the function
print([(x.value, y.value) for x.value in range(5)])
# prints [(0, 0), (1, 5), (2, 13), (3, 26), (4, 42)]
```

Comment: Is there such a class? Paul: "Now there is!". I wish I had more upvotes.

Comment: I stand on the shoulders of a giant, er, Python? (Do Pythons have shoulders?)

Comment: Excellent!  For symbolic algebra, it has some shortcomings yet, but that is no criticism.  You have to take care what you assign to `x.value`: with integers you get unexpected results.  Also some symbolic operations would be nice: What is `-y` in the example above.  @PaulMcGuire: I will take that as an excercise because I was recently experimenting in a similar direction but I did not come up with anything nearly as concise as you.

Comment: If by "you get unexpected results" with integers, perhaps you refer to the surprises of integer division. If you want to force all expressions to evaluate using floating semantics, you could store values into Parameter using `self.value_ = float(v)`, or take care with your expressions to use integer division vs. float division operators.

Answer (score 7):

You could give [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy), a computer algebra system written in Python, give a try.

E.g.

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> y = 2 * (x + 2) ** 2 - 8
>>> y
2*(x + 2)**2 - 8
>>> y.subs(x,3)
42
>>> y.subs(x,2)
24
```

Comment: Not to downplay your answer, but out of curiosity: what is the benefit of this construct over using a function? I seems less legible, and you still have to construct it in code... I'm honestly interested in the added value of the library in this case.

Comment: @jro: The OP has effectively asked for a library for algebra, this is a library that (among other things) does algebra. Over a function, this would allow an equation of multiple symbols to be solved or expressed where the substituted values include symbols.

Comment: This comes closest to what I had in mind, since I can build the expression in several steps. However, with this method I need to call a special function to have it evaluated -- I wanted it to be seamless and giving `x` a value from the start. But maybe I can subclass `Symbol` and have a lot less work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this called a `function`? This may sound like a simple answer, but I mean it sincerely.

```
def y(x):
    return 2 * (x + 2) ** 2 - 8
```

Aren't you thinking in the wrong direction with this one?

To address the clarification:

```
class MyParams():
    distance = 0.0
    speed = 0.0
    def __call__(self):
        return self.distance / self.speed

p = MyParams()
p.distance = 13.4            # These are properties
p.speed = 3.14               # where __get__ returns MagicNumber instances
time = p()  # 4.26
p.speed = 2.28
time = p()  # 5.88
```

I guess I'm more in favor of this type of a solution, although I see the benefit in the sympy module. Preference, I guess.

Comment: I do not know beforehand which arithmetic operations will be performed, and I may not assume that they are done all at once, or in the same place.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea then to update your question with some intended use cases. How exactly are you going to construct these operations, and why don't you want to map a character (say, `*`) to a function (say, `multiply`)?

Comment: Re: update. Again you lock me down to a particular problem. I can not forsee what kinds of parameters or problems the user of my module wishes to do. He should be free to name the parameters himself and use them as he sees fit, and to calculate with them just as if they were normal values. I just want to give him the extra ability to retroactively change them.

Comment: Wait, so the end-user will type in the code you put in your question's first code block? In that case, you could wrap up the call in an `eval` command, replacing the variables upon execution: e.g. `eval('2 * (x + 2) ** 2 - 8'.replace('x', str(3)))` -- `3` being the current value of the `x` parameter?

Comment: Ok, the background is appreciated. From what I can envision about your issue, I still stand by this solution though; probably because I don't see the problem with creating a class with some variables defined in them, along with a calculate function that can be cleanly annotated and desribed. I'll leave my answer as-is, and suggest you pick the solution that is the closest match to your personal preference (which I think this boils down to).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> magic = lambda x: eval('2 * (x + 2) ** 2 - 8')
>>> magic(2)
24
>>> magic(3)
42
>>> magic = lambda x: eval('x ** 4')
>>> magic(2)
16
>>> magic(3)
81
```

Comment: @eumiro, he does not know beforehand which arithmetic operations will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difficulty is in "how to keep operators priority" rather than implementing a class.

I suggest to look at a different notation (like [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)) that may help in getting rid of priority issues...

Comment: I think the Python interpreter will take care of the priority issues - he doesn't want to parse the expression, he wants to capture the parsed expression as an evaluatable (is that a word?) object.