# Overriding operators within functions

Tags: python, overriding

I want to define operators for a class instance within a class function, like so:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @property
    def _arithmetic_threshold(self):
        return self.threshold # this will be defined somewhere

    @_arithmetic_threshold.setter
    def _arithmetic_threshold(self,value):
        self.threshold = value
        self._define_arithmetic_attributes()

    def _define_arithmetic_attributes(self):
        """
        Wrapper to define all arithmetic attributes (in order to allow threshold changes)
        """

        self.__add__ = self._operation_wrapper(np.add,threshold=self._arithmetic_threshold)
        self.__sub__ = self._operation_wrapper(np.subtract,threshold=self._arithmetic_threshold)
        self.__mul__ = self._operation_wrapper(np.multiply,threshold=self._arithmetic_threshold)
        self.__div__ = self._operation_wrapper(np.divide,threshold=self._arithmetic_threshold)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - I feel like I'm missing something about how the operators `-`,`+`, etc, call these functions.  i.e.:

```
class MyClass2(object):
    def __add__(self,other,threshold=None):
        if threshold is not None:
            return self+other
        else:
            # do something here involving checking a threshold....
            pass
```

in MyClass2, the behavior of `__add__` will be different.  Can anyone explain how they are different, and how to make the behavior of the operator methods in MyClass similar to MyClass2?

EDIT: Just to make clear why I'm trying to do this, here's `_operation_wrapper`.  The class this is a method of is a "Spectrum" object, which has an X-axis and a Y-axis.  The goal is to allow arithmetic on the Y axes, but only if the X axes match.  However, it is acceptable for them to match to, say, 1/5th of a pixel size, so I wanted to do more that pure 'exact' matching.

```
def _operation_wrapper(operation):
    """
    Perform an operation (addition, subtraction, mutiplication, division, etc.)
    after checking for shape matching
    """

    def ofunc(self, other): 
        if np.isscalar(other):
            newspec = self.copy()
            newspec.data = operation(newspec.data, other) 
            return newspec
        else: # purely for readability

            if self._arithmetic_threshold == 'exact':
                xarrcheck = all(self.xarr == other.xarr)
            else:
                if self._arithmetic_threshold_units is None:
                    # not sure this should ever be allowed
                    xarrcheck = all((self.xarr-other.xarr) < self._arithmetic_threshold)
                else:
                    xarrcheck = all((self.xarr.as_unit(self._arithmetic_threshold_units)-other.xarr.as_unit(self._arithmetic_threshold_units)) < self._arithmetic_threshold)

            if self.shape == other.shape and xarrcheck:
                newspec = self.copy()
                newspec.data = operation(newspec.data, other.data)
                return newspec
            elif self.shape != other.shape:
                raise ValueError("Shape mismatch in data")
            elif not xarrcheck:
                raise ValueError("X-axes do not match.")

    return ofunc
```

Comment: For an advanced (and cool) example of operator overriding, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7844038/566644) fantastic answer to a question I asked on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special methods like `__add__()` are looked up on the *type* of the object, not on the instance.  So

```
a + b
```

is roughly translated to

```
type(a).__add__(a, b)
```

This means that setting `__add__` on the *instance* does not do anything useful (except for making `a.__add__(b)` work).

Your example is a bit incomplete, so I can't provide full working code.  You might be able to move the code from `_define_arithmetic_attributes()` to the class body and access `self.threshold` from inside `operation_wrapper()`.

(Note that I don't get the point of the `_arithmetic_threshold` property.  Why don't you simply access `self.threshold` itself?)

Comment: Good question about the `property` - I've updated the example to demonstrate what I intended.  Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?  i.e., re-set the `__add__` method depending on the threshold?  What I'm really trying to do is allow arithmetic between two instances only if some of their properties (the X-axis of a spectrum...) agree to within some threshold, otherwise raise an exception

Comment: in retrospect, your comment about accessing `self.threshold` inside `operation_wrapper` is probably the way to go.

Comment: @keflavich: To give you more information, I would need to know what `_operation_wrapper()` looks like.  Maybe there's a completely different approach.