# Passing arithmatic expressions in python without evaluating them

Tags: python, variables

I've searched and couldn't find a direct answer for my question, so apologies if this has already been posted/answered before. I'm working in python and i need to pass expressions that contain variables, but i don't want them to be immediately evaluated.

For example:

```
r = x*y
```

I want the program to remember that in order to calculate r, it needs to multiply x and y instead of explicitly calculating it at the time. I've tried using:

```
x = None
y = None
r = x*y
```

But this doesn't allow operations on the variables. I've managed it using strings and then using "eval" but its not a very elegant solution, and its also painfully slow. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried lambda expressions (which are actually function objects)?

Comment: I asked a very similar question over a year ago, and got [this most excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7844038/566644) that got way less votes than it deserved.

Comment: What is your real goal here? I think there would be a much cleaner solution if you could tell us. I think you have a design problem, not a python problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `lambda` expression:

```
>>> x = None
>>> y = None
>>> r = lambda : x*y
>>> r()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> r()
2
```

You could even get a little more fancy with a class:

```
class DeferredEval(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self):
        return self.func()

    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.func() + other

    def __radd__(self,other):
        return other + self.func()


x = None
y = None
r = DeferredEval(lambda:x*y)

try:
    a = 1 + r
except TypeError as err:
    print "Oops, can't calculate r yet -- Reason:",err

x = 1
y = 2
print 1 + r
print r + 1
```

with the output:

```
Oops, can't calculate r yet -- Reason: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
3
3
```

Of course, here you'll need to add a whole bunch more methods if you want to do things that aren't addition, subtraction, ...
Of course, then you have to actually *call* `r` in order to get your result -- but that's not so bad is it?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it was extremely useful. I need to also be able to edit the expressions, which i don't think is possible using lambda, but your example of a class has provided a lot of food for thought. Cheers.

Comment: @NathanBush -- What do you mean "edit" the expression?  You can always just replace it with a new one:  `r = lambda : x+y`.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the [source code](http://utilitymill.com/edit/Math_Evaluator)  of the [Math Evaluator](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Math_Evaluator) utility to get an idea how to create expressions for evaluation later on. This [demonstration](http://ideone.com/AxRv4X) on [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) helps to show what the code can accomplish.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run a simple demo that shows evaluator's capability.
    namespace = {}
    expression = tokens('x * y -> r')
    print expression
    evaluate('2 -> x; 3 -> y', namespace)
    expression.evaluate(namespace)
    print 'r =', namespace['r']
    alternate = Operation(Operation(Variable('x'), '+', Variable('y')), '->', Variable('r'))
    print alternate
    alternate.evaluate(namespace)
    print 'r =', namespace['r']
```