# Sympy expr_parse() causing function evaluation to fail

Tags: python, parsing, sympy

I have been poking around the sympy library and I have run into an issue specifically when trying to evaluate a parsed function. If I manually enter the function, like function(2z), it evaluates as expected. However, I need to be able to use this class to take strings, but I cannot get the expected output.

```
from sympy import I, re, im, Abs, arg, conjugate, Symbol, symbols, lambdify
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.abc import z
import numpy

class function(object):
    def __init__(self, expre):
        self.z=symbols('z',complex=True)
        if isinstance(expre,str):
            self.expre = parse_expr(expre)
        else:
            self.expre=expre
        self.f_z=lambdify(self.z, self.expre, "numpy") #taking advantage of the reuse of the function object. Lamdba numby operations greatly speed up operations on large amounts of data with inital overhead

    def evaluateAt(self,w):
        return self.f_z(w) #return the result!

z=symbols('z',complex=True)
funct=function(z**2)
print(funct.evaluateAt(complex(1+1j)))

funct=function("z**2")
print(funct.evaluateAt(complex(1+1j)))
```

With the output being:

```
2j
z**2
```

I have tried using "sympify" to no avail as well. I'm pretty sure I am just doing something really off-base, but don't know where to go from here.

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820771/python-number-like-class-that-remembers-arithmetic-operations) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than subclassing from `object`, you should subclass from `sympy.core.function.Function` class.

```
from sympy import Function


class some_func(Function):

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, expr, sym):
        # automatic evaluation should be done here
        # return None if not required
        return None


    def evaluateAt(self, pt):
        return self.args[0].subs(self.args[1], pt)

>>> s = some_func("z**2", "z")
>>> s.evaluateAt(complex(1 + 1j))
(1.0 + 1.0*I)**2
>>> s.evaluateAt(complex(1 + 1j)).expand()
2.0*I
```