# Is there a way to print the math that makes an integer in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have this code:

```
int1 = (2 + 2) * 4
print(int1)

OUTPUT: 16
```

But is there a way to print the math of the int without using a string instead? Like a `literal()` function or something?

Example program:

```
int1 = 2 + 2
int2 = 4

print('{} times {} equals:'.format(literal(int1), literal(int2))
print(int1 * int2)

OUTPUT:
2 + 2 times 4 equals:
16
```

I kind of feel like I'm looking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist, but I'm new to Python and I'm curious.

Comment: I don't think there is a function for that, however it should be easy for you to create your own

Comment: The more straight-forward approach would be to use strings, and then evaluate them. Using `eval` wouldn't be unsafe unless you were getting your strings from untrusted inputs, if they are from the source code it's fine. So, `expression = "2 + 2"; result = eval(expression);`. If the strings do come from untrusted input, then you can use a simple parser written with the pyparsing library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371789/5014455

Comment: But what you *may* really be looking for is a "computer algebra system", a popular library for this is [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html)

Comment: I suppose I may be looking at this backwards. Perhaps it makes more sense to create the string "2 + 2" and then pick that string apart to find the numbers, symbols, etc., and then do the math from there.

Comment: If this is something you are doing in a Jupyter Notebook, look into using handcalcs. https://pypi.org/project/handcalcs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar, except storing the literal firm in a string, and using the `simple_eval` method from the [`simpleeval`](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/) module:

```
from simpleeval import simple_eval

int1 = '2 + 2'
int2 = 4

print('{} times {} equals:'.format(int1, int2))
print(simple_eval(int1) * int2)
```

Output:

```
2 + 2 times 4 equals:
16
```

`simpleeval` is a module that safely evaluates math expressions, as opposed to the infamous `eval` method, that allows malicious attacks to your OS.

Comment: Interesting. I assume (without trying it) that you could also use simple_eval on ``int2`` and it would work just the same?

Comment: Marking this as the answer! It maybe isn't the "best" way to do it, but it certainly makes the most sense to a beginner, and avoids the issues with ``eval``, which I wasn't even aware of. Now I have more reading material!

Answer (score 2):

Native python 'forgets' the operations you made, and just remembers the values of the variables you have. So when you do `x = int1 * int2`, python allocates the corresponding value to `x`, but does not store anything about the operations which yielded this value.

However, it could be a (not so easy) coding exercise: design your own integer class which stores the history of computations.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Math():

    def __init__ (self):
        self.val = 0
        self.opList = []
    def add(self,val):
        self.val += val
        self.opList.append(" + "+str(val))
    def sub(self,val):
        self.val -= val
        self.opList.append(" - "+str(val))
    def printOps(self):
        print(self.val," = 0",end="")
        for i in self.opList:print(i,end="")

t = Math()

t.add(10)

t.sub(5)

t.printOps()
```

python does have operator overloading but it looks like a pain to write

Comment: Output would be 5  = 0 + 10 - 5

Comment: Python absolutely *does* have operator overloading. See https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: Used in this answer of mine from a few years back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820771/python-number-like-class-that-remembers-arithmetic-operations/7844038#7844038

Answer (score 1):

> The more reasonable approach would be to use strings, and then evaluate them. Using `eval` wouldn't be unsafe unless you were getting your strings from untrusted inputs, if they are from the source code it's fine.

*-- [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959667/is-there-a-way-to-print-the-math-that-makes-an-integer-in-python#comment116621848_65959667) by [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)*

```
int1 = '2 + 2'
int2 = '4'

print('{} times {} equals:'.format(int1, int2))
print(eval(int1) * eval(int2))
```

Output:

```
2 + 2 times 4 equals:
16
```